# Swift: Failed to assign value to a property of protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, properties, swift-protocols

Class A provides a string value. Class B has two members of A type inside itself, and provide a computed property "v" to choose one of them.

```
class A {
    var value: String

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class B {
    var v1: A?
    var v2: A = A(value: "2")

    private var v: A {
        return v1 ?? v2
    }

    var value: String {
        get {
            return v.value
        }
        set {
            v.value = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

This code is simple and it works. Since both the A and B have a member "value", I make it a protocol like this:

```
protocol ValueProvider {
    var value: String {get set}
}

class A: ValueProvider {
    var value: String

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class B: ValueProvider {
    var v1: ValueProvider?
    var v2: ValueProvider = A(value: "2")

    private var v: ValueProvider {
        return v1 ?? v2
    }

    var value: String {
        get {
            return v.value
        }
        set {
            v.value = newValue // Error: Cannot assign to the result of the expression
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the following code

```
v.value = newValue
```

to

```
var v = self.v
v.value = newValue
```

It works again!

Is this a bug of Swift, or something special for the property of protocols?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to define the protocol as a `class` protocol:

```
protocol ValueProvider : class {
    var value: String {get set}
}
```

Then

```
var value: String {
    get { return v.value }
    set { v.value = newValue }
}
```

compiles and works as expected (i.e. assigns the new value to the
object referenced by `v1` if `v1 != nil`, and to the object
referenced by `v2` otherwise).

`v` is a read-only computed property of the type `ValueProvider`.
By defining the protocol as a class protocol the compiler knows
that `v` is a *reference type*, and therefore its `v.value`
property can be modified even if the reference itself is a constant.

Your initial code example works because there the  `v` property has
the type `A` which is a reference type.

And your workaround

```
set {
    var tmp = v1 ?? v2
    tmp.value = newValue
}
```

works because (read-write) properties of *variables* can be set in
any case (value type or reference type).