# Specify a settable property/variable in a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I would like my protocol to declare that there is a read/write property available. I have attempted it, but this does not work:

```
protocol EdibleThing {
  var eaten: Bool { get set }
}

class Pickle: EdibleThing { var eaten = false }
class RusticGrapefruit: EdibleThing { var eaten = false }

class Jar {
  let contents: [EdibleThing] = [Pickle(), RusticGrapefruit()]
  var nextItem: EdibleThing {
    return contents.last ?? Pickle() // Lazy pickle generation technology
  }
  func eat() {
    let food = nextItem
    food.eaten = true // (!) ERROR: Cannot assign to result of this expression
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I think I've declared that the protocol has a get/set var called `eaten`, so why can't I set it?

Comment: I've also tried more direct access: `func eat(food: EdibleThing) { food.eaten = true } // ERROR: Cannot assign to 'eaten' in 'food'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Failed to assign value to a property of protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728753/swift-failed-to-assign-value-to-a-property-of-protocol).

Comment: Pretty similar Martin. My case is a lot more concise, the answer as well I think.

Comment: It's the same problem and the same solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol might be implemented by either classes and structs - that prevents you from changing the internal status of an instance of a class or struct implementing that protocol using an immutable variable.

To fix the problem you have to either declare the `food` variable as mutable:

```
func eat() {
    var food = nextItem
    food.eaten = true // (!) ERROR: Cannot assign to result of this expression
}
```

or declare the `EdibleThing` protocol to be implementable by classes only:

```
protocol EdibleThing : class {
    var eaten: Bool { get set }
}
```

Note that this happens because `food` is a variable of `EdibleThing` type - the compiler doesn't know if the actual instance is a value or reference type, so it raises an error. If you make it a variable of a class type, like this:

```
let food: Pickle = nextItem as! Pickle
```

the compiler knows without any ambiguity that it's a reference type, and in that case it allows the assignment. But I guess that breaks your app logic... so consider it just as an example

Comment: any docs on this class thing? I don't see them in the Swift book's protocols section

Comment: It's in the _Protocols_ chapter: [Class-Only Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281)

Comment: It's definitely not in "Swift: A Programming Language" iBooks book (verify by searching `: class` or `SomeClassOnlyProtocol `). I'm going to stop using it as reference, keeps biting me with out of date stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating `food`.

Replace `let food = nextItem` with `var food = nextItem`

Comment: Huh? But I can assign class instances to `let` vars all day long without issue, and mutate their properties. Is the issue that the protocol type could be implemented by a class or a struct and it doesn't know?

Comment: EdibleThing might be a struct as well, well @Antonio was faster ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't mutate a property on a value type defined by `let`.

Even though both of `RusticGrapefruit` and `Pickle` are class implementations (reference types), the protocol could be assigned to a value type like a struct. The compiler detects a potential problem and stops us.

Two solutions:

1. Change `let` to `var` (in my case, this would mean changing a lot of code that refers to objects of this type. Also, I like the semantic value and possible compiler optimizations from `let`)
2. Declare the protocol as only valid for classes: `protocol EdibleThing: class { }`

Comment: Thanks to Thomas for pointing me in the right direction on this. Oh, and Antonio, too!