# What is an elegant way of modifying last element of an array?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of custom class objects and I need to modify a property of the last element. I know "last" and "first" are implemented as getters, however, that doesn't help me :) Is there another way than accessing the last element by index?

**UPDATE**

```
protocol DogProtocol {

  var age: Int {get set}
}

class Dog: DogProtocol {
  var age = 0
}

var dogs = Array<DogProtocol>()
dogs.append(Dog())
dogs.last?.age += 1 // Generates error in playground: left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'last" is a get-only property
```

Comment: 1. you should explain why `.last` doesn't help you. 2. what's wrong with `array[array.count - 1]`?

Comment: @ozgur in obj-c, last and first were safe to access methods, meaning it won't crash if array is nil or empty

Comment: I know what they are used for. So you want your app to crash when you access the last element of an empty array?

Comment: @Hamish compiler says cannot assign to property: first is a get-only property. Check class definition.

Comment: @ozgur Well, writing more code was never a preferred option for me. I will use indexes if there's no another way, but array.last is definitely more convenient than "array[array.count - 1]' :)

Comment: `array.removeLast()`, `array.last?.someProp = ` , `array.count-1` ..etc.

Comment: `(dogs.last as? Dog)?.age += 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Failed to assign value to a property of protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728753/swift-failed-to-assign-value-to-a-property-of-protocol). – Solution: Make the protocol a *class protocol*: `protocol DogProtocol: class {...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that works. It shows that you can modify the last element's properties without issues.

```
class Dog {
    var age = 0
}

let dogs = [Dog(), Dog()]
dogs.last?.age += 1 // Happy birthday!
```

However, it sounds like you are trying to replace the last element with something like `dogs.last? = anotherDog` instead of modifying it.

**Update:**

Interesting. I don't actually know why the protocol changes the behavior (I guess I should study protocols more), but here's a clean solution:

```
protocol DogProtocol {
    var age: Int { get set }
}

class Dog: DogProtocol {
    var age = 0
}

var dogs: [DogProtocol] = [Dog(), Dog()]

if var birthdayBoy = dogs.last {
    birthdayBoy.age += 1
}
```

Comment: This only works if the things inside the array are reference types.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work with this protocol, because it is not restrained to reference types. If you add inheritance from AnyObject to the protocol then it will work.

Answer (score 12):

Safe (in case of empty) and elegant:

```
foo.indices.last.map{ foo[$0].bar = newValue }
```

Mind you only do this with `Sequences`s (like `Array`) as with collections getting the last index may require iterating the whole thing.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it this way

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]

arr[arr.endIndex-1] = 5
```

it would give you

```
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Btw, maybe this question is a duplicate

EDIT:

array safe access
[Safe (bounds-checked) array lookup in Swift, through optional bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings)

Comment: The only problem here is that an empty array will crash the app.

Comment: I added a link to a nice extension giving you a safe access to array indexes in swift. ultimately, you can still you a good if arr.count { } before accessing the last item.